# How to manage two different size of textarea box in css

Tags: html, css

In css I need two different size textarea boxes.
[image]

My Jsfiddle code link is:---[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/v21wdzp7/)

But Now I am getting same `textarea`..What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Try using either of rows/cols in HTML OR height/width in css. For explanation see the answer i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign two different ID and then style them:

```
<div class = "tablebox">   
<form>
<label for="emailaddress">address</label>
<textarea cols="73" rows="12" name="descr" id="texta1"></textarea><br />
<label for="comments">About you </label>
<textarea name="comments" id="texta2"></textarea><br />
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tablebox 
{

  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

}

label{
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
font-weight: bold;
}

input{
width: 80%;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

textarea{
width: 50%;
height: 300px;
}

#texta1{
width: 30%;
height: 300px;
}

#texta2{
width: 70%;
height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: whats the use of overriding properties of height and width for textarea in CSS? it is totally invalid. Also there are cols and rows attributes along with that which has no reason to stay if you use height and width in css.

Comment: Ya no offense, but if people start such things here i guess no one could have this Answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Give different height to the both textarea  id's.

```
 textarea1 { height:10%; }
 textarea2 { height:20%; }
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ons:

```
.tablebox 
{

  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

}

label{
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
font-weight: bold;
}

input{
width: 80%;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

textarea1 {
     height:10%;
}
 textarea2 { 
     height:20%;
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/v21wdzp7/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Textarea has two attributes `rows` and `cols` which are similar to `height` and `width` respectively, properties of CSS.

So i would suggest you to use either of them not the both. If you are designing **Respoonsive Design**, must use CSS `height & width`properties.

For instance removed(comments) css for textarea.

```css
.tablebox 
{
 
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 
}

label{
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
font-weight: bold;
}

input{
width: 80%;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

textarea{
/*width: 50%;
height: 200px;*/
}
```

```html
  <div class = "tablebox">
      
 <form>
<label for="emailaddress">address</label>
<textarea cols="73" rows="12" name="descr"></textarea><br />

<label for="comments">About you </label>
<textarea name="comments" ></textarea><br />

</form>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add different classes to the textarea and specify the styles in css for textarea.

Eg: HTML

```
<form>
<label for="emailaddress">address</label>
<textarea class="textarea1" cols="73" rows="12" name="descr"></textarea><br />

<label for="comments">About you </label>
<textarea class="textarea2" name="comments"></textarea><br />

</form>
```

css

```
.textarea1{width: 150px; height: 30px;}
.textarea2{width: 300px; height: 60px;}
```